# How to fix errors when installing modules in a Docker image?

Tags: python, pip, dockerfile, streamlit

I encountered an issue while making a docker file wherein the message:
"ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install streamlit" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1" popped up, and I can't figure out why I'm struggling to install the streamlit module into my image via the file.
I've included a copy of my dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3-alpine3.15
WORKDIR /myapp_dir
COPY . /myapp_dir/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install python-dotenv
RUN pip install streamlit
RUN pip install PyPDF2
Run pip install langchain
EXPOSE 8501
CMD streamlit run app2.py
```

So help me in figure out what's the error and also how to see the error that encountered during creating image. Is there any way to figure out error in it?
[image]

Comment: Provide the full stack trace of the error;

Comment: And do not post text as image.

Comment: I'm not familiar with obtaining a complete stack trace for an error. Can you enlighten me with some guidance as I'm relatively new to this?

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with different approaches, I found out that I was able to eliminate the errors by changing my Python image from "python:3-alpine3.15" to simply "python" as my base image.

I'm not sure why, but I believe the reason is that Python has a larger version image compared to the lightweight Alpine image.